# Cookies are always expired

Tags: c#, cookies

I am setting a cookie with:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("simpleorder");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
cookie["order"] = carModel.ToString();
cookie["price"] = price.ToString();
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

But when I check it a few seconds later it is expired and the expiration date is set to {01-01-0001 00:00:00}. I try to retrieve the code by

```
 HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["simpleorder"];
 if (cookie != null && cookie.Expires > DateTime.Now)...
```

I don't clear the cookie any place, so I don't know why it expires?

Comment: Do you update your cookie ? If you update your cookie, without setting expiration time, it will no longer exists.

Answer (score 22):

This is common mis-understanding.  The Request cookie collection represents the cookies included in the requests cookie header.  Such cookies do not contain any info regarding when they expire.  Strictly speaking .NET ought to have used two different types (RequestCookie and ResponseCookie) but instead chose to use the same type for both circumstances.

The Expires value only makes sense when adding cookies to the response.

Comment: So the only way to check if a cookie is expired is to check if it exists?

Comment: A common solution, if you need to know the expiry date, is to save it as a value inside the cookie. It could suddenly get out of sync, but if it's a httponly cookie, you have the power to make sure it doesn't happen ;)

Answer (score 5):

At first I was also disappointed that request cookies don't have the `Expires` value, but after debugging using Fiddler2, I know that the http protocol does not include any `Expires` value for request cookies. The .NET Framework has no way of exposing `Expires` value for request cookies.

If you use Fiddler between your app and the browser, you can see the response cookie sent correctly to the browser with all properties. However, the request cookie in the http headers doesn't have the expires value, it only exposes cookie name and value. Browsers are required to send this request header, as specified in the http standard. The reason why could be to minimize size and web servers don't need to check anything other than the values.

So you do not need to check the `expires` value on web request, because it is what you set it to be on some earlier web response. If you receive the cookie back,  that means the cookie is not yet expired. Once you set the `expires` value, the browser will handle the expiration. If you want to change the expires, just set the new value on the response.