# .Net cookies keep coming back with expiration of zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, cookies

I am having trouble with the .Expires cookie attribute.  It keeps coming back with 01/01/0001 12:00 AM, when I read the cookie back.

Here is the code.  I added in the retrieve just below the save solely for debugging purposes.  The save and retrieve happen in different places in the same file.  I purposely did not specify a Domain, as I want the cookie to exist site wide.

The data shows up nicely, just not the expiration.

Note: I am testing under Visual Studio 2012 running under local host using .Net Framework 4.

```
System.Web.UI.Page oPage = this.Page;

HttpCookie oCookie = new HttpCookie("UserData");

// Set the cookie value.
oCookie.Secure = false;
oCookie["Field1"] = strField1;
oCookie["Field2"] = strField2;
oCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

// Add the cookie.
oPage.Response.Cookies.Add(oCookie);


// Get the cookie.
oCookie = new HttpCookie("UserData");
oCookie = oPage.Request.Cookies["UserData"];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser will not send anything to the server except the cookie name and value. All of the other properties (expires, domain, path, httponly, ...) cannot be retrieved on requests after the cookie has been set.

The more accepted way to deal with this is to redirect the user to a login page when they try to access a protected resource and display some message along the lines of "You need to log in to view this page. If you were previously logged in, your session may have expired."

(Also note that you should be re-setting the cookie on every request, so that the user will not be logged out if they continue to use the site. It's not clear from your code whether you are doing this or not.)

Comment: I am not resetting the cookie on every request.  I did not know that I need to do that.  Thank you.  It makes sense, though.

Answer (score 1):

I was just doing some more Google searching on my problem and saw this link, another posting here on Stackoverflow.

[Cookies are always expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735836/cookies-are-always-expired)

I am also validating using the construct:

```
if (cookie != null && cookie.Expires > DateTime.Now)...
```

As several pointed out, expiration checking happens, if you can no longer retrieve the cookie.  That is seriously dumb on whomever constructed this architecture.  Yes, maybe there should be RequestCookie and ResponseCookie, the difference being ResponseCookie has no Expiry date.

The person who resopnded to me taught me that it is not just expires but other fields too.

Answer (score 0):

In C# code, if using Form Authentication, You can find if cookie is persistent using below code 
`bool IsCookiePersistent = ((FormsIdentity)User.Identity).Ticket.IsPersistent;`

Here `Ticket` will return the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` which has `Expiration` DateTime property.