# Why do Request.Cookies and Response.Cookies both use the same object?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Request.Cookies and Response.Cookies both contain a collection of HttpCookies, however, the usage of the Cookie object differs in each. For example, the value contained in Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Expires seems to be useless, since browsers don't actually send the expiration date back to the server with the request. But since this field exists, it causes a lot of confusion with developers assuming the field has meaning, trying to use it, and then inevitably searching to find out why the expiration date is always 1/1/0001. There are other unused fields as well when looking at a cookie in the Response vs the Request because they are used in different ways, so I wonder:

What are the potential design reasons why a single class (HttpCookie) is used for both a request cookie and a response cookie, given the usage concerns noted above?

Edit: I see some people have voted to close this question because it is too opinion based. Someone certainly might know the answer to this, e.g. it was designed this way because of X. I would also be interested in knowing someone's best guess too, if no one outside of MS knows what X is.

Edit 2: Another valid answer would be that it was probably an oversight and they should be different objects.

Answer (score 0):

I never found this in my original searching, but I'm guessing Anthony's response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735836/cookies-are-always-expired) is probably the best I'm going to get. He proposes:

> Strictly speaking .NET ought to have used two different types (RequestCookie and ResponseCookie) but instead chose to use the same type for both circumstances.

I'll happily accept an answer that offers valid reasons (or conjecture) for why that choice was made, if it was intentional.