# cookie expire date null in web api

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-web-api

this is a simple question. I have an application that make use of cookies. The thing is that when I make a GET to the server, the cookie 'Expires' property is always null. I need to get that value.

Anyone knows why this is happening and how to solve it?. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you set the `Expires` property in a previous request?

Comment: Yes I have set that property. Anyway, I found some answer that cleared up all for me. I´m doing a bad use of cookies on this case... take a look at this post... speccially AnthonyWJones answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735836/cookies-are-always-expired